# Use my model to predict output in tensor flow 2 without using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am new to TensorFlow and I have a very basic question. I have found several posts regarding this question for the previous TensorFlow versions but I could not use the answer for TensorFlow 2 which I am using. The examples I found in the documentation in the original site use Keras.

Now, about my question, say, I have built my own model using only TensorFlow without using Keras. I have finished training my model and now I want to use my trained model to predict output for some input I give.

I am starting out very simple in order to learn to use TensorFlow 2. I am stuck here and it would be of great help if someone provides me a solution. I have attached my snippet of code herewith.

```
# Defining input and output placeholders
x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(128, 128, 1, 1)) # Placeholder for input
y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(128, 128, 1, 1)) # Placeholder for ground truth 

inp = np.ones([128,128,1,1]).astype(np.float32) # Dummy input dataset I made
                                                # I will use it both for input and ground truth to train my model
# My neural network model
pred = my_model(x)

# Defining my optimizer, I am using gradient descent and l2 norm loss
l2_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.subtract(pred, y), name=None)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.000001

# Training the model
training_iters = 300
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  summary_writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter('./Output', sess.graph)
  for i in range(training_iters):
        dataset_dict = {x: inp, y: batch_y}
        opt = sess.run(optimizer.minimize(l2_loss), feed_dict = dataset_dict)
        loss = sess.run(l2_loss, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        print(loss)
  summary_writer.close()

# Use my trained model to predict output for some input I give
# ??
# ??
```

Comment: I recommend reading through the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager), you'll find plenty of examples of what you want to do. In general, tf2 does not use placeholders anymore (nor the concept of sessions, at least not on higher levels), you should customize your model gradients using [tapes](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff) and final code should be wrapped in a [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs) ( for performance and portability.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was reimplementing codes for TensorFlow 1 in TensorFlow 2, plus I am new to TensorFlow. It created some confusion for me about running sessions because I saw TF 2 supported it. I think they put it for backward compatibility. But, that you for clearing that up.